# Workbench email

Tags: 7, workbench

I have workbench Moderation module installed for moderating the content through three states and also using workbench email to send emails when there is any state changes.

In workbench Email There is option of sending email to Node Author when Node changed from Needs Review -> Published.

But other person (not Author) can edit the content and push it to Needs Review, Is there any way that Person will get email about Node Publishing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using the Rules module -- https://www.drupal.org/project/rules

Add a new rule: admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add

Enter a title and optionally, a tag

Select "After moderation transition" in the Node category for the "React on event" field

Click Save

Add a condition

for the "Select the condition to add" field, select "Content's current moderation state" in the node category

Leave the default "node" for the "Data Selector" field in the Content fieldset

Select "Needs Review" for the Value field in the Workbench Moderation State fieldset

Click Save

Add an action

For the "Select the action to add" field select "Send an email" in the System category

Next page, the TO fieldset

Click the "switch to data selection" button

Enter "node:author:mail" into the Data Selector field

Enter values in the Value field for the Subject, Message, and optionally the From and Language fieldsets

Click save.

You'll have a rule that sends an email to the author every time a node transitions to the Needs Review moderation state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I did this by using rules module and custom module to get a token for Revision author email.